# Way to set a formula using counter as cell reference in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set a cell's value to a formula, but the formula includes a counter because the column is always set, but the row of the cell varies during every initiation of the macro. How do I set this up? This is what I have, but it keeps giving me an object-defined error.

```
counter = activecell.row
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(AH & counter &, reference)"
```

The reference part is set up correctly, but I don't know how to get the first part to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, you do not want R1C1 format and vba variables need to be outside the `""` and concatenated with `&`

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AH" & counter & ",...
```